# Element type is invalid (Error): got "undefined"

Tags: reactjs

*Reactjs Context Provider Error*

`Error: Element type is invalid: <br/>expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here is a preview of my codebase:

```js
// components/Search.js
import React from 'react';
import { Paper, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  state = { searchterm: '' }  
  handleChange =(event) => this.state ({searchterm: event.target.value});      
  handleSubmit =(event) => this.state ({searchterm: event.target.value});

  render(){
    return (
       <Paper elevation={6} style={ {padding: '25px' }}>
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           <TextField fullWidth label="Search..." onChange={this.handleChange}/>
         </form>
       </Paper>
     )
  }
}    
export default SearchBar;

// components//VideoDetail.js
import React from 'react';

const VideoDetail = () => {
  return <h1>this is a video detail componetnt </h1>
} 
export default VideoDetail;
```

The above are exported below:

```js
// components/index.js

export { default as SearchBar } from './SearchBar';
export { default as VideoDetail } from './VideoDetail';
export { default as VideoList } from './VideoList';
```

And they're imported for use within the `App` Component:

```js
// App.js
import React from 'react';
import { Grid } from '@babel/core';
import  { SearchBar, VideoDetail } from './components';

class App extends React.Component {
  render (){
    return(
      <Grid justify="center" container spacing={16}>
        <Grid item  xs={12}>
          <Grid container spacing={16}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>{/* <SearchBar onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/> */}</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={8}>{/* <VideoDetail/> */}</Grid>
            <Grid item xs={4}></Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
     );
   }
 }
export default App;
```

Am doing anything wrong in there?

Comment: `import { Grid } from '@babel/core';` ? thats obviously a mistake

Comment: Did importing `Grid` the right way solve this error?

Comment: @MwamiTovi Yeah